# How to remove a dependency in Gradle depending on the Spring Boot runtime environment?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Not sure if this is a Gradle question or a Spring Boot one, but here goes...

I am using Spring security and LDAP in a spring boot application.

I have the following dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:3.2.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-server-jndi:1.5.5'
```

The second of these supplies an embedded LDAP server that is only needed during development.

I have established a SB @Profile and configure/load an LDIF file into the embedded server within a class that has the @Profile('development') annotation.

The question is: how to remove the second dependency when not in dev mode?

I establish the spring.profiles.active property within my config/application.yml file, thusly:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: development
```

Can I reference spring.profiles.active so that I can somehow exclude the unneeded dependency?

Comment: What does it mean *not in dev mode*? How is other mode prepared? War? Command line? What determines it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, what I ended up doing...

At the top of my build.grade file:

```
def readActiveProfile() {
    final config = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().loadAll(new File('config/application.yml').newReader())
    final defaultPart = config?.take(1)
    defaultPart?.spring?.profiles?.active
}

final activeProfile = readActiveProfile() ?: ['development']
```

This reads the config file that I am keeping my externalised settings in (one of which is the setting defining the active profile).

And then, in the dependencies section:

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:3.2.4.RELEASE'
if( ! ('production' in activeProfile))
    compile 'org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-server-jndi:1.5.5'
```

This works well enough for my purposes, but doesn't feel quite right; I was assuming that there would be a more idiomatic "Gradle way" of doing this.

Comment: forgot to mention, I added `classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14'` to the buildscript's dependencies.

Comment: Would you made showing us your full/most of your `build.gradle` file please?d